# Which is a good way to achieve object persistence in php

Tags: php, oop, memcached

Hello guys i try to get an object global/persistent over more than one php page, so that i do not need to load it everytime.

I read a lot but in the moment i am not really sure, which is now the best way to achieve that, when the object is a bit bigger with e.g. ten multidimensional arrays with each 100 variables or more.

1. The easiest way i think, is to use the session, serialize and unserialize it. But what is about the performance?
2. Store the object in database and send a query to get its values. Maybe faster as Session but in handling not that comfortable?
3. Store the object memcached, but this is only a good solution if i had enough of it. I have a problem with that. What is enough here meaning? In the docs there was not any handy information about it. My managed server has 8 GB Memory...
4. Store the object on the harddrive. Maybe the slowest way?

5.
Another method?

I appreciate any help, link, tutorials, maybe performace checks and so on to better understand this. Maybe one of you can explain which of the methods above should i prefer and why.

Thanx ruven

Comment: When you store something in a session I think it also will be stored in a session file on your harddrive.

Comment: Abstract this component so you can switch between memcache/session/apc solution easily. Then build your first version - as I've found from personal experience, it is better to build something that is non-optimal than to be stuck in analysis paralysis `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Ruven:**

the best and the fastest way is to hold the data in the RAM. So in think there are more solutions.

You can use your session like you said and set the session handler to memcache. Then all session data is automaticly stored in memcache.

The second way is to make a "MEMORY" table in your database and store the data in this Table. Then the sessions are stored in RAM but if you restart your server the data from the MEMORY table is lost.

The easiest way is to set memcache as session handler but i am interested in more ideas here.

Comment: do somone know a site with a comparison of the methods? Especially for memcache i would like to know how much ram i should have to use this.

Comment: Its depending how much data you will store to memcache. But perhaps you should thing about a better structure and have a look at design patterns. Another solution is to make a class which holds the data and give the class to the other classes. Something like the Factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Actually default http sessions write session data on the filesystem so i'll delete option 4 as option 1 should be equals in terms of performance and is easy to manage.

I suggest to use memcache as memchace stores data mainly in memory RAM. Under memchached a persistent layer can be set like a database. This way even if you finish the memchached available memory you won't loose data.

Answer (score 0):

> The easiest way i think, is to use the session, serialize and unserialize it. But what is about the performance?

Suboptimal, and I think it's not even the easiest way. I think using [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.installation.php) would greatly improve performance, and using [apc_store](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php)( $name, $var ) is not much harder than putting something in a session.

Comment: ah yes apc and xcache i forgot in my list. But it is also a way to store data on the harddrive. maybe it would been better to summarize that methods...

Comment: @RuvenJR.Maerson Yes, but instead of having to deal with invalidating cache yourself, you can let APC do that for you. You want caching, and caching is hard. Using APC is the easiest way. ;) Obviously, using memcache is certainly a good way of using RAM for caching.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the duration of the lifetime of the object, I would either choose Memcached or Redis.

Memcached if the object can live for a few minutes or hour, and if it can be safely purged from cache and reconstructed in your code, since objects in memcached have an expiration time, and can be overwritten at anytime if there is not enough memory.

Redis, which is like memcache but with more data types and a persistence layer if you need your objects to live longer. Your objects will essentially be stored in memory, but serialized to hard drive when necessary. Item expiration exists, but is optional. See http://redis.io/ for more details.

Comment: so this is a method using both "technologies" hardrive and Ram? Interesting.

Comment: Yes indeed, I've started using Redis as the main back-end for a business-critical web app, and I must say that its performance is great !